# Post a tweet via OAuth with just JavaScript

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, javascript

I am trying to figure out a way to post a tweet via just JavaScript to twitter for a personal project of mine. It won't be publicly accessible, so I'm not worried about security, which is normally something you have to worry a lot about with OAuth through JS.

Essentially I want to: redirect to twitter OAuth login -> accept -> redirect back to my own page -> tweet/do something.

I have been looking forever, and I can't seem to find a way to do this (I can't find any good JavaScript OAuth libraries either). I wouldn't have imagined it would be this difficult.

Any recommendations/solutions?

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but the reason you're having a difficult time finding info on this is because Twitter still uses Oauth 1, which is a REALLY bad idea to use with client side JavaScript. Having said that, it does seem like there is a library here, though I haven't tried it: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Comment: You could also use the Chrome extension library, if you're okay with writing a Chrome extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html

Comment: None of those seem too direct though, really just looking for raw javascript. I might just try to roll my own, unless there is anything I might be missing.